# I can not compare view.getBackground() == R.drawable.image ?[android]

Tags: view, android-imageview, android-drawable

I need to compare the image loaded as background into my imageView. I do so like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.hero1:
                    if(v.getBackground() == R.drawable.hero1){
                    //do something
              }
                    break;
                case R.id.hero2:
                 //other stuff
          }
```

But v.getBackground() does not compare to what I have in drawable folder.
Why?

Note that v.getBackgroundResource() is not available.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this-

```
  @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.hero1:

                      if (v.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hero1).getConstantState())) {
                         // Do something here
                      }

                        break;
                    case R.id.hero2:
                     //other stuff
              }
```

Comment: what is constant state?

Comment: You can read it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState.html